# How to implement Simulated Annealing at Nodes(TSP)

Tags: javascript, java, simulated-annealing

I need to program something like Traveling salesman problem but with nodes.I need to get the an Amount with less misalignment.

I don't know how to implement the Simulated Annealing Algorithm with the Boltzman Constant.

I have coded the first part:

`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Amount 
{
    private ArrayList amount; //List of all nodes
    private int ak; //Number of all nodes
    private Random rand; //random

```
public Amount(int a)
{
    amount = new ArrayList<Node>();
    ak = a;
    rand = new Random();

    int i = 0;
    while(i < ak)
    {
        Node k = new Node();
        amount.add(k);
        i++;
    }

    this.connect();
}
public ArrayList<Node> giveAmount()
{
    return amount;
}
public void connect()
{
    for(int i=0;i<ak;i++) //We gradually go through all the nodes and add neighbors to it        {
        for(int j=0;j<ak;j++) // We go through all the nodes again and add them with 20% probability as neighbors from the current node i
        {
            int k = rand.nextInt(10);
            if(k < 2 && i != j) //20% chance of connection, not possible with himself                {
                if(amount.get(i).showNeighbor().contains(amount.get(j)) == false) // Double neighborhood is avoided
                {
                    amount.get(i).newNeighbor(amount.get(j)); // j is stored as the neighbor of i                    }
                if(amount.get(j).showNeighbor().contains(amount.get(i)) == false) // Double neighborhood is avoided
                {
                    amount.get(j).newNeighbor(amount.get(i)); // i is stored as the neighbor of j                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}`

How can I implement the Simulated Annealing here with those nodes??

I know I need something like this`prob = Math.exp(-(proposal - current) / temperature)`

Can someone give me a sample code for this?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to read and try https://stackabuse.com/simulated-annealing-optimization-algorithm-in-java/

Indeed, the probability part is

```
    public static double probability(double f1, double f2, double temp) {
        if (f2 < f1) return 1;
        return Math.exp((f1 - f2) / temp);
    }
```

Is part of the example.